# How to auto space list elements within a div

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that has these tabs at the top which I need to have automatically spaced inside a `div`. The reason for this, is that the div below it has a border that needs to line up with the borders on the tabs. See my jsfiddle below for what I'm talking about. I currently have them all spaced correctly, but the nature of this site is that the words in the tabs will change, making my spacing incorrect. How can I automatically space them inside my div so I don't have to tinker with all the individual padding to make them line up with the div below?

http://jsfiddle.net/g7c5X/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to achieve it by adding to your CSS something like this:

```
    #navMenu ul {display:table; width:100%}
    #navMenu li {display:table-cell}
```

I think older versions of IE may ignore the display type can't remember which.  The other option would be some javascript to calculate the margins.

Comment: I think most of our clients use IE since our biggest user is Microsoft. That would be bad. I guess I'll calculate margins.